# CakePHP: route with optional parameters

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

Suppose that I have this action:

```
public function index_by_date($year = NULL, $month = NULL, $day = NULL) {
    if($year && $month && $day) {
        //Posts of day
    }
    elseif($year && $month) {
        //Posts of month
    }
    elseif($year) {
        //Posts of year
    }
    else {
        //Exception...
    }
}
```

This shows the posts of a single day (all posts of 06/11/2016):
`mysite.com/posts/2016/06/11`

This shows the post of a full month (all posts of June 2016):
`mysite.com/posts/2016/06`

This shows the post of a full year (all posts of 2016):
`mysite.com/posts/2016`

I think this is clear.

Now I want to write a single route for all these cases. Then, the second and the third parameter should be optional.

I have tried something like this, but this does not work:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:year/:month/:day',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_by_date'], 
    [
        'year'  => '[12][0-9]{3}',
        'month' => '(0[1-9]|1[012])?',
        'day'   => '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?',
        'pass'  => ['year', 'month', 'day']
    ]
);
```

How to do?

---

**EDIT**
For now, this is the best that I could do:

Route:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:date',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_by_date'], 
    [
        'date' => '\d{4}(\/\d{2}(\/\d{2})?)?',
        'pass' => ['date']
    ]
);
```

Action:

```
public function index_by_date($date = NULL) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = array_merge(explode('/', $date), [NULL, NULL, NULL]);

    if($year && $month && $day) {
        //Posts of day
    }
    elseif($year && $month) {
        //Posts of month
    }
    elseif($year) {
        //Posts of year
    }
    else {
        //Exception...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

### Not supported

Better drop the idea of defining this as a single route with separate route elements, that's not supported, neither by the route compiler/matcher, nor by reverse routing.

While you could create a custom route class that supports this, you'd have to completely reimplement route compiling, and implementing reverse routing support would probably be just as fun - personally I don't think that it's worth the hassle.

### Use multiple routes, or custom route classes

So either write multiple routes, which is what I'd most probably do, or go with a parameter parsing solution like you are showing here.

When chosing the latter, it should better be done in a custom route class to make things more DRY. But there would still be the disadvantage that you'd need to pass the date parts as a single string when building URLs, unless you'd also implement some custom matching, like checking whether the `year`, `month`, `day` keys are present, and build a new URL array to match against.

I have a little too much free time right now, and such parsing/matching might generally be interesting, so here's a quick & dirty example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Routing\Route;

use Cake\Routing\Route\Route;

class CompactDateRoute extends Route
{
    public function parse($url)
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (!$params) {
            return false;
        }

        $params['pass'] = explode('/', $params['pass'][0]) + [null, null, null];

        return $params;
    }

    public function match(array $url, array $context = [])
    {
        $dateParts = [];
        foreach (['year', 'month', 'day'] as $key) {
            if (!isset($url[$key])) {
                break;
            }
            $dateParts[] = $url[$key];
            unset($url[$key]);
        }
        if ($dateParts) {
            $date = implode('/', $dateParts);
            return parent::match($url + compact('date'), $context);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The parsing part should be pretty self-explantory, it simply parses the single date string into separate parameters, which will then be passed to your controller action as separate arguments. Note the usage of `+` instead of `array_merge()`, the latter would *append* the `null` values!

The matching part also isn't overly complicated, it simply checks for the date part keys in the URL array, builds a compact date value (`year/month?/day?`) from it that could match your route, and matches against that, ie building a URL from an array like

```
[
    'controller' => 'Posts',
    'action' => 'index_by_date',
    'year' => '2014',
    'month' => '12',
    'day' => '04'
]
```

will basically equal matching against

```
[
    'controller' => 'Posts',
    'action' => 'index_by_date',
    'date' => '2014/12/04'
]
```

However, all that, just for being able to define this with a single route? Again, I'm not sure that it's worth the hassle.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Custom Route Classes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)**

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3, you could add the '_name' option to the $routes->connect() and separate the three different routes.

Full date, routes.php:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:year/:month/:day',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_by_date'], 
    [
        'year'  => '[12][0-9]{3}',
        'month' => '(0[1-9]|1[012])?',
        'day'   => '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?',
        'pass'  => ['year', 'month', 'day'],
        '_name' => 'postsFull'
    ]
);
```

Usage (in call):

```
['_name' => 'postsFull', 'year' => '2016', 'month' => '06', 'day' => '11']
```

Year with month, routes.php:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:year/:month',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_by_date'], 
    [
        'year'  => '[12][0-9]{3}',
        'month' => '(0[1-9]|1[012])?',
        'pass'  => ['year', 'month'],
        '_name' => 'postsYearMonth'
    ]
);
```

Usage (in call):

```
['_name' => 'postsYearMonth', 'year' => '2016', 'month' => '06']
```

Only year, routes.php:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:year',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_by_date'], 
    [
        'year'  => '[12][0-9]{3}',
        'pass'  => ['year'],
        '_name' => 'postsYear'
    ]
);
```

Usage (in call):

```
['_name' => 'postsYear', 'year' => '2016']
```

I hope this helps you.